# Ansible/Junos_OS - Return of variable comes unindented

Tags: ansible

so I'm using this simple playbook as an example:

```
- name: Show interfaces
  junos_command:
    commands:
    - show interfaces
    display: text
  register: json_response
```

And I need to save json_response to a file:

```
- name: Saving logs to output
  copy:
    content: "{{ json_response.stdout }}" 
    dest: "./output.txt"
```

I know that json_response.stdout_lines has the real organized json, but when I save it, it comes ALL unindented, and if I use "json_response.stdout" it comes "indented" but he doesn't recognize '\n' as a breakline character, so I execute another task to replace \n to breakline. My problem here is, anyway I can save json_response variable in a correctly way? When I execute the playbook the debug var prints perfectly indented on my shell, but doesn't work for my output file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of the formatting filters, e.g. like this:

```
- name: Saving logs to output
  copy:
    content: "{{ json_response.stdout | to_nice_json(indent=4) }}" 
    dest: "./output.txt"
```

More details and examples can be found in the [Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data).